# Django - update another model on save in admin

Tags: python, django

I am using django to create a video library website.

I have 3 models for the library: Video, VideoTopic, and Course.

I have a TimedeltaField for the duration of each Video.  Upon saving each video in admin, I want to get the sum of each TimedeltaField for all Videos within a Course, then save that sum to a TimedeltaField in my Course model.

I'm using [django-timedeltafield](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-timedeltafield), which will handle the summarization very well.  What I have yet to find a solution for is how to update the Course model after I save each Video in admin.  Any advice?

My models are as follows:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    topic = models.ForeignKey('VideoTopic')
    duration = timedelta.fields.TimedeltaField(default="3 minutes, 30 seconds", help_text="(x minutes, x seconds)")

class VideoTopic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey('course.Course')

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    duration = timedelta.fields.TimedeltaField()
```

Comment: You only want to update it in admin, or always?

Comment: always keep it updated would be best.

Comment: Video needs a relation to Course. Add `course = models.ForeignKey('Course')` to your Video model. And keeping it updated won't be best. Because you need a lot of code to keep track of the total video duration. Read about database normalization. The total time can be retrieved with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: You can't say if keeping it updated is not best; your advice is over generalized. Normalizing has its uses, but can also be a performance killer. Combine that with the need here to do several joins (in the current schema) and aggregate queries, the result could be a painfully slow query (and often is). It will of course depend on the volume of data, indexes, underlying db, etc. This is exactly why a huge number of applications these days do map/reduce jobs, denormalize, and pre-store things - aggregate queries in real-time always cut it, while they may be alright in a report scenario.

Comment: Depends if the asker wants "bank" accurate time or not as well. If not, a write-heavy approach, i.e. calculate on save is far better. We don't understand the access patterns, so I am sticking to the askers actual question.

Comment: @therewillbesnacks: Yes, you're right. My comment is over generalized and should have been a suggestion. You are right about the joins too. I would avoid those as well. A poor schema can't be an excuse to denormalize. Renkai: Are you experiencing performance issues?

Comment: Hi there isn't any performance issue at this point.  I expect only around 10-20 videos per topic, then no more than 7-8 topics per course.  Thanks for all your input it's been very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use a [django signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). This will ensure your models are synchronized regardless of where they are updated (in the app, admin, etc.).

Register the [post save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal on the Video. In the signal, you will receive the video instance. Simply query for its related records in VideoTopic and Course and do the math there. I recommend doing all this in the transaction if you don't want it to ever fail. If you don't need the information always up-to-date, it's also an opportunity to do some background work to make the save lighter weight.

Why a signal?

- Separates concerns
- Ensures your logic always runs
- Can help decouple things out of the model directly if it has dependencies, which can cut down on some situations of loading order/circular dependencies.

Alternatively, you could simply override the Video model's [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method and do the same thing there. In either case, just use the related properties in the ORM from your foreign keys if you don't want to write the queries yourself.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to override the admin save method to update the course model.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods.